# Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/8.5.6 (7.0.2) Oracle JTS/XA-Datasource Configuration

Tags: oracle, apache-tomee, xa, jts, tomee-7

Has anybody a running example configuration for:

- Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/8.5.6 (7.0.2) PLUME
- Oracle 11g (ojdbc7.jar)

to match EE/JPA 2.1-Development as near as possible?

Currently i get TomEE's user database, if i try to use my datasource. I think it's caused by the log entry "org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.deploy Found matching datasource: jdbc/jKgvDS but this one is not a JTA datasource", falling back to the last known running datasource. So how can i configure a valid JTA datasource?

**server.xml:**

```html
<Resource id="jKgvDS" name="jdbc/jKgvDS" 
                      jtaManaged="true"
                      auth="Container"
                      type="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource" 
                      
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource"
                      factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"
                      url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@db:1521:db"
                      username="myuser" 
                      password="mypass" 
                      maxActive="20"
                      maxIdle="30"
                      maxWait="-1"
                      validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
            />
```

**context.xml (tried in conf and app-file)**

```html
<ResourceLink global='jdbc/jKgvDS' 
name='jdbc/jKgvDS' type="javax.sql.XADatasource" 
auth="Container" />
```

**persistence.xml**

```html
<persistence-unit name="jKgvPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/jKgvDS</jta-data-source>        
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>
        <properties>
            <property
                name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary"  
value="org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.OracleDictionary" />
            <property
                name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary"
value="oracle(maxEmbeddedBlobSize=-1,maxEmbeddedClobSize=-1)" />
            <property
                name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings"
                value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go (yeah...):

```html
<Resource id="jKgvDS" name="jdbc/jKgvDS" 
                  jtaManaged="true"
                  auth="Container"
                  type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
  driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
 factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
                  url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@POSDBORA:1521:posdbora"
                  username="myuser" 
                  password="mypass" 
                  maxActive="20"
                  maxIdle="30"
                  maxWait="-1"
                  validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
        />
```

References in web.xml or context.xml are not needed to run.